# Rails 4 - how to set a timezone for strftime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, timezone

Every user in our database can select his/her own timezone. The default timezone of our application `Eastern Time`:

```
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

When I display some dates/times in the application, I usually use for that purpose `.strftime`. How can I give a parameter to `strftime` to display the date/time properly (in the given timezone for the specific user)?

Or is there a better way than to format every date/time with using `strftime`?

**EDIT:**

Every user has a `time_zone` string column, where is stored the timezone like this: `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`.
As the every date/time will be re-calculated for every timezone, how about the performance? Will this not slow down too much rendering views?

Answer (score 5):

Set your time object `in_time_zone()` before `strftime`.

Say you're displaying `created_at`, you'd do:

`object.created_at.in_time_zone(current_user.timezone).strftime("...")`

Comment: There is also posibility to extend `Time::DATE_FORMATS` hash and use it like `Time.now.to_s(:db)`.